# How does Javascript handle function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I recently had an issue with some javascript that goes against every bone of my programming background. Javascript does this often to me, so I'm not that surprised.

I have a function as such...

```
function x(param1, booleanParam, arrayParam){
    ....
}
```

I was getting a runtime error saying that `arrayParam.length` was not defined. On debugging I saw this was true and went to find out why. Turns out I had forgotten a comma in my function call as such...

```
x(param1, true [arrayJunk]);
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out why this call was made at all? Why isn't this a compile error, how does Javascript see this and think, "Yeah, that seems like it might work!"

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment you can share!

Comment: This is a case where using the `Array` constructor instead of the literal syntax would have provided a useful SyntaxError, but then you have the potential issue of passing a single numeric argument causing a different silent bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an indexing expression.
It's the same syntax as `someArray[someIndex]`.

It will end up passing `undefined` as the second parameter too, unless `arrayJunk` happens to be the name of a property of boolean primitives.

Comment: Is `true` not a reserved word in javascript? How can it try to do an index on a primative?

Comment: @Shaded: In Javascript, everything is an object.  For example, `true["toString"]()` will return `"true"`.

Comment: Not everything is an object; `1, true and "23443"` are primitives. Only things where `typeof` returns "object" are real objects. But everything can be converted into an object, and that's what the JS engine does

Comment: @SLaks: Well, almost everything. `null` and `undefined` don't have properties.

Comment: null does not auto convert into an object

Comment: *"...happens to be the name of a property of boolean primitives"* You probably mean a property of `Boolean.prototype`. Primitives can't have properties.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to goad you into stating everything in javascript is an object, I know it can start a war. It just blows my mind that javascript takes `true` and creates an object out of it. Old habits from C and Java die hard I suppose. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

What happens is the following:

- JavaScript engine converts `true` into a `Boolean` object (not the primitive)
- It then tries to access the property name stored in `arrayParam` from that object
- Property doesn't exist, so it returns undefined

If `arrayParam` was the string `"toString"`, it would return a function object

Answer (score 0):

In this case the expression was being interpreted as an index.  Essentially the same as

```
someArray[42]
```

So it was being seen as a function call with 2 parameters instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

Many dynamic languages don't check if you pass too many or too few arguments to a function.

While this can sometimes mask errors, it also allows you to roll your own defalut parameter scheme.